# xcode warning - directory following -L not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I'm getting the following warning when I try to build my project:
Directory '(directory name)' following -L not found

The directory name refers to an SDK that I had added to my Resources folder, but have since removed. The problem is that I have no idea how to remove the reference to the directory that is causing the warning. I can't find any reference to it anywhere in my build settings.

Can anyone help me? I am using Xcode 3.2.5.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like an orphan header search path. Make sure to check both your project's and your target's build settings (they can be different).

Comment: Yes you were right, the path was in the target's build settings. I hadn't thought to look there. Thank you very much!